# How to disable text wrapping when viewport border is reached?

Tags: html, css

Consider code snippet below (*you can click and drag outside the text*) - the text is wrapping when viewport border is reached.

```js
let isCaptureActive = false;
let offset = {
    x: 0,
  y: 0
}
const fooDOM = document.querySelector('#foo');
const bodyDOM = document.body;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if(!isCaptureActive) return;

    offset.x += e.movementX;
  offset.y += e.movementY;
  
    fooDOM.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
  fooDOM.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if(e.target !== fooDOM) isCaptureActive = true;
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    isCaptureActive = false;
});
```

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: wheat;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porta nisl justo, id rutrum lorem cursus in. Nullam dictum lobortis lorem, vitae facilisis lectus. Donec ut eros lacinia, suscipit nisl ut, convallis diam.
</div>
```

How to make text **ignore** viewport border like it's not even there?

**EDIT:** I need to be able to set the element's `min-width` and `max-width` attributes.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible, if you set a `min-width` and a `max-width`. The container will change its width depending on how much space is available. If you move the element close to the boundaries of the viewport, the container decreases its width because the available space narrows. That's how CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let isCaptureActive = false;
let offset = {
    x: 0,
  y: 0
}
const fooDOM = document.querySelector('#foo');
const bodyDOM = document.body;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    if(!isCaptureActive) return;

    offset.x += e.movementX;
  offset.y += e.movementY;
  
    fooDOM.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
  fooDOM.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if(e.target !== fooDOM) isCaptureActive = true;
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    isCaptureActive = false;
});
```

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: wheat;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
#pg {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
<p id='pg'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porta nisl justo, id rutrum lorem cursus in. Nullam dictum lobortis lorem, vitae facilisis lectus. Donec ut eros lacinia, suscipit nisl ut, convallis diam.
</p>
</div>
```

I simply wrapped the text inside a `<p>` element and set its width to 100vw.

Comment: I don't think that the author intends to overflow the `foo` container.

Comment: as he said how to disable word wrap.